# gdb always program exited with code 01

Tags: gdb

I am using scientific linux. I am trying to compile a project that uses a bunch of cpp files. Right now, it compiles successfully, but the values/data I'm getting are definitely wrong.

In the directory `user/project/Build`, I enter make to compile and link all the cpp files. I then have to go to `user/run/` and then type `./run.sh values.txt`

When I go to directory `/user/project/Build/bin` and then type `gdb project` and then set breakpoints, there are no problems. But when I hit run, I always see `Program exited with code 01`. It doesn't matter if I set breakpoints in main.cpp or another source file. Isn't gdb supposed to stop at the breakpoint?

Comment: "Exited with code  N" just refers to the value returned from `main()`.  Does it show the correct path in `Starting program:` after you `run`? Using `gdb ./project` (an absolute path) is less error prone.  Beyond that, this seems kind of impossible to solve unless you provide at least an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Are you saying `gdb` does this with, e.g. `hello world`?  I bet it doesn't.  You have to narrow down the difference.

Comment: yes, it shows the correct path. I also get the same result if I try `gdb ./project`. Not sure how I can provide an SSCCE. I have main.cpp and a bunch of other cpp files, and each of them have 1000s of lines of code. The program usually runs if I go to `user/run` and then type `./run.sh  values.txt`

Comment: If it matters, the entire output before `program exited with code 01` is `[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
warning: File "/opt/apps/ossw/applications/gcc/gcc-4.6/sl6/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.16-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your 'auto-load safe-path' set to "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load:/usr/lib/debug:/usr/bin/mono-gdb.py".
ProjectName -[function option] <parameter file>
`

Comment: That's about some [autoload file](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto_002dloading.html#Auto_002dloading); e.g. a common python one (`.py`) used with C++ is for prettified dumps of standard container structures.  Not loading it probably isn't the cause of your grief.  Gilles' answer makes an excellent point, but if that doesn't solve things, you need to start with a breakpoint on the first line of code in `main()`.  If things are still confused...you are perhaps in over your head.  Debugging can break hearts, that is the nature of the beast. :(

Comment: ...If you can find someone responsible for this code, they might be able and willing to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use the trick.

set the break point in exit.

gdb ..

b exit

run ..

bt

so you can know where the main call the exit funciton

Answer (score 1):

`user/run/run.sh` is presumably (given the name) a shell script that sets up things that the program needs to run. Likely things are setting environment variables and passing command line arguments. To set environment variables and command line arguments in GDB, use

```
set args = arg1 arg2
set env VAR1 = value1
set env VAR2 = value2
```

Read the shell script to see what it is actually doing.

Comment: I read run.sh to see what it does. Why do I need to set environment variables and set values like you listed in GDB?

Comment: @user4352158 So what does `run.sh` do? If it sets up environment variables or passes arguments, you need to do the same thing when you invoke the program under GDB.